# How to calculate the Jones vector in the following setting

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection

Calculate the refractive index of gold at a wavelength of $632.8$ nm using the simplified Drude model for metals.

Assume linearly polarized light at $45$° that is incident at an angle of $80$° on a golden surface.

Find the Jones vector for the polarization of the reflected light.

The final answer needs to be of the form

$\begin{vmatrix}  A \\ Be^{iC}  \end{vmatrix} \\$

with A, B and C numbers (only relative phases are important !).

careful : $\phi$ is in radians

I already calculated the refractive index of gold ( $n^2= -20.15$, $n= 4.49i$ )
and the $R_p$ and $R_s$. However, both $R_p$ and $R_s$ have an imaginary and real part, I don't know whether that is correct.

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsStackExchange, please avoid pasting images of text. Type in everything needed for the question formatting math using MathJax/LaTeX. This way the text becomes searchable for other users.

Comment: @ohneVal Thank you for the tip!

Comment: In principle, both components of the Jones vector can be complex valued. It is just traditional to push (algebraically manipulate) the complex parts into the second component, as you've written the "final form." Have you tried doing this with your answer? This is basically an expression of the fact that the Jones vector is just a phasor in the complex plane. As you said, only the relative phase is important. This is also true for quantum states, but that's another story!